# Cannot install libclang-dev and build-essential

Tags: ubuntu, apt

If i try to install libclang-dev and build-essential:

```
sudo apt install libclang-dev
sudo apt install build-essential
```

I get the following error (at bottom of page), but how can I install the correct libc6 I have already tried to swap to an older version, update & upgrade and

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

None of it worked

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because there is no `libclang-dev` in the ubuntu apt package.

you should look at this :

[image]

you should choose one of these:

> libclang-10-dev          libclang-8-dev
> libclang-common-6.0-dev  libclang-cpp10-dev       libclang-cpp1-9
> libclang-11-dev          libclang-9-dev
> libclang-common-7-dev    libclang-cpp11           libclang-cpp9
> libclang-12-dev          libclang-common-10-dev
> libclang-common-8-dev    libclang-cpp11-dev       libclang-dev
> libclang-6.0-dev         libclang-common-11-dev
> libclang-common-9-dev    libclang-cpp12           libclang-perl
> libclang-7-dev           libclang-common-12-dev   libclang-cpp10
> libclang-cpp12-dev

you also can Search before installing something like :

```
sudo apt-cache search libclang
```

**Please see [How to use apt-cache search to find packages](https://linuxhint.com/apt_cache_search_packages/) for more information.**

and be **sure** you **should use `sudo apt-get update` before installing anything.**

For [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237) you should see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223267)

> You can get a list of actual held packages with:
>
> `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`
> If there are none, or none look related, then it's probably something
> else. Check carefully the output of the command you were trying when
> you got the error message, as there may be other clues in the full
> output from that command, aside from the error message.